# How to base64 encode emojis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I've been trying to encode a twitter embed code into base64 that may or may not contain one or multiple emojis. So when there is an emoji in the string, I get this error:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Is there anything I can do so that when I run btoa() on my string, it encodes the whole string including the emoji, and when I decode it using base64_decode in php, the emoji appears again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why bother? It's a text string. It isn't binary. What's the point of converting it to ASCII? What system are you transporting the data through that can't handle UTF-8?

Comment: @Quentin, it's a shortcode generated using JavaScript and then interpreted by PHP. If I directly pass the data without encoding, all the quotation marks create a big mess and haven't found a way to escape all kinds of quotes.

Comment: JSON is traditional

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can encode it by escaping it first and then calling EncodeUriComponent on it.

This looks like this:

```js
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent('')));
```

The emoji above would return "8J+Ygg=="

To decode it you would do this

```js
decodeURIComponent(escape(atob('8J+Ygg==')));
```

You could make two functions that make this a bit easier:

```js
// Encode
function utoa(str) {
    return btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}
// Decode
function atou(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(str)));
}
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Comment: `escape` is not unicode safe and is therefore deprecated. `escape` is a means to express data in ASCII. `btoa` is a different way to express data in ASCII. Combining them is utterly pointless.

Comment: encodeURIComponent is what I needed — no need for base64 anymore

Comment: I don't see anything on Google Chrome `v91` when running the exmaples

Answer (score 4):

Use js-base64 library as

```js
var str = "I was funny ";
console.log("Original string:", str);

var encodedStr = Base64.encode(str)
console.log("Encoded string:", encodedStr);

var decodedStr = Base64.decode(encodedStr)
console.log("Decoded string:", decodedStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-base64@2.5.2/base64.min.js"></script>
```