# emoji() in a file to html with js

Tags: javascript, file, unicode, emoji

i have a file:`t.js` which contains,

```js
s='';
```

then i open/view `index.html`, which contains,

```html
<script src='t.js'></script>
<body>
<script>
document.write(s);
</script>
```

but my output is,

```
ðŸ«€
```

so i tried doing something with these

```js
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent('')));
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647747/how-to-base64-encode-emojis-in-javascript#56647993), still no difference at all.

so, is there a way to display  from my file, without using any external packages/libraries like *js-base64* ?

Comment: If you properly declared that you're using UTF-8, and the file is actually UTF-8 encoded, this should work as is. See: HTTP Content-Type charset header (on the HTML and/or JS file), HTML meta charset element, possibly `charset` attribute of the `script` element.

Comment: Running what you have in a snippet here works perfectly

Comment: @deceze that's totally helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `charset='utf-8'` to the script tag's attributes

```js
<script src='t.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<body>
<script>
document.write(s);
</script>
```

& worked...

now its output is,